# command line showing sql result in hebrew

Tags: sql, oracle, cmd

I try to run sql command in the cmd and the result showing in hebrew like this:

```
C:\Users\owner>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on ß π÷εß° 26 14:14:16 2011

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


ετσß° α∞: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 
64bit Production With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real 
Application Testing options

SQL> alter system switch logfile;

Σε≥°δ· ·σ≈≡Σ.

SQL> /

Σε≥°δ· ·σ≈≡Σ.

SQL>
```

I have windows 7 Home Premium in English and Oracle DB.

Comment: That's not Hebrew, it's Greek to me :):):)

Comment: Unless stackoverflow messed it up... yep, its not Hebrew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure, this is Hebrew? Looks like Greek. Anyway, check two things:

- Your system locale
- Oracle `NLS_LANG` settings: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html . Also, try to set `NLS_LANG` to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1`

Answer (score 0):

Add new Environment variable:

```
NLS_LANG = AMERICAN_AMERICA.IW8ISO8859P8
```